# Whats the difference between the smallest connected spanning subgraph and a eulerian path?

Tags: graph-theory

I personally don't think there is much difference? Apart from for the smallest connected spanning subgraph that the smallest connected subgraph MUST have n-1 edges where n is number of vertices but this isn't necessarily the case with Eulerian paths?

Comment: An Eulerian path is a path (ordered sequence of edges) that visits every edge exactly once; a minimum connected spanning subgraph is a subgraph that maintains connectivity and has as few edges as possible... the two notions are distinct.

Comment: by definition it seems distinct but if it visits all edges exactly once then it implies? that it has the minimum number of edges and since it visits all edges then its also connected

i agree they are distinct i dont think though its obvious? that they are. or specifically how.

Comment: For example: if your graph $G=(V,E)$ is dense, then any Eulerian path must have by very definition $\lvert E\rvert = \Theta(n^2)$ edges. But a connected spanning subgraph could have as few as $n-1$ edges. Also, an Eulerian path is an *ordered list* of (all) edges (the order in which you visit the edges is at the very core of the notion!) while a connected spanning subgraph is a subgraph... there is no ordering in its edges at all, and in general not all edges from the original graph will even be present.

Comment: (One confusion you seem to make is that a spanning connected subgraph needs to connect all **vertices**, but does not need to (and in general will not) have all **edges**.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same. Any connected graph has a smallest connected spanning subgraph. However, there exists connected graphs without eulerian path. Don't forget that an eulerian path is not really a subgraph, but more an order on the vertices: $v_0, v_1, \ldots v_{n-1}, v_n=v_0$ such that $v_iv_{i+1}\in E(G)$ for all $i$ and all $v_i$'s are distinct (that means any edge can only be picked at most once)

For example, if you take a star-shaped tree $T$ (with at least 4 vertices), its smallest connected spanning subgraph is $T$ itself (because removing an edge would leave a disconnected subgraph) however, there is no eulerian path.